# a few basic xcode questions

Tags: xcode

1. what is copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)
2. is this a good option? If I dont choose it will it just make a reference to my files?
3. Also if I have two images with the same name like /images/home.gif, /public/home.gif
4. but they are in different groups how does the compile know which image to use?  is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have a crack at this :-)

1 & 2 - Used when adding files to a project. If selected, the file you are adding is copied into the projects directory from wherever it originally was. Note it is copied. If not selected, the project can still use it, it just has a reference to the original source file. Which means that if something happens to the original file, the project will not longer have a copy it can use. Personally for files such as images I copy them into the project so they stay with the project. For other things such as external apis, I don't because I don't want multiple copies everywhere.

3 - If you have two images with the same name you won't be able to copy them in without renaming one. XCode may do this for you, I've never tried. I'd suggest renaming one so you control it's name.

4 - Don't get confused by groups. They are logical groupings of files within XCode and do not refer to the underlying file system. Having said that you can actually assign a directory to a group so if you really wanted to you can match the two. I tend to do it a little. In my projects I generally have a src and test directory. I setup two groups and assign them to refer to these directories. Then when I create a new source code file I can create it in the src or test group and it will be created in the sub-directory instead of the project root directory. Often below src and test I will use other groups, but they do not map to any sub directories. The result is that the root directory of the project is free of source code files and the source code also has source and test code separated.

Comment: is there an easy way to figure out which files are referenced and which ones are copied?  I would like the reference files to be copied over.

Comment: Don't know. I'd agree that would be useful.